# Bibliography after Appendix, but supposed to be not PART of it

Tags: bibliographies, appendices, bookmarks

I'm using document class **scrbook**.
I want to put my bibliography after appendix (in source this starts with `\appendix`), but in my toc that is visible when I open up the generated PDF file, it is a part of the appendix. Is there a way to make it the same level as appendix but not create a whole new part in the document (i.e. manipulate only the toc?). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One should distinguish between the Table of Contents and the bookmarks: the former is part of the printed document, the latter is a property of the PDF previewer. From what you say the problem seems to be with the bookmarks.

Add `\usepackage{bookmark}` *after* loading `hyperref` (it's one of the few packages that should be called so) and, just before the bibliography in your document, say

```
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already adding your bibliography, and just want it to appear separately in your table of contents, the following should work.

From the LaTeX wikibook, to add a section (in this case Bibliography),

```
\clearpage %Should be added directly above bibliography, if 1 sided
\cleardoublepage %If 2 sided, thanks to egreg
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter/section/subsection etc.}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{bibliography name} %Or other command to add bibliography
```

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` would be better (with `\clearpage` the page number might be off by one when `twoside` is used).

Comment: Yes, this adds the part-level `bibliography` entry, but also a subentry `bibliography` because the bibliography creates its own TOC entry...