# Adding Bibliography after Appendix, without including it

Tags: bibliographies, appendices

I'm currently working on a document that is based on the Elsevier document format (`elsarticle`), and I have a bunch of sections, then an appendix, followed by a bibliography section. It is structured as such:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
% some content
\appendix
\input{appendix}
\section{References}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

The appendix section header now says "Appendix A: [title]", but the references section header says "Appendix B: References". How do I indicate that the appendix section has ended, and that we're now in the new bibliography section? This question seems related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48551/bibliography-after-appendix-but-supposed-to-be-not-part-of-it), although I'm not using a table of contents. The solution proposed there did not work for me.

Comment: The code you have given is not a Minimal Working Example : It can not be compiled.

Comment: The best way is to replace `\section{References}` as `\section*{\refname}`.

Comment: In the class you are using, `\appendix` changes the settings globally so it is not easy to limit its effect to a portion of the document without redefining the command. If your document is meant for submission check whether this order is acceptable to the publisher before changing the command's meaning

Comment: Perhaps replace the `\appendix` switch by the `appendices` environment (from the `appendix` package), that will be closed before the references section?

Comment: Using `\section*{\refname}` worked like a charm. Thanks @SunilkumarKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macros of `\appendix` in the `elsarticle.cls` prefixes the string **Appendix** in the section heads.

```
\def\appendixname{Appendix }
\gdef\thesection{\appendixname~\@Alph\c@section}%
```

Thus, the best way is to use `\section*{\refname}` instead of `\section{References}`.